# chef Improve powershell_script performance

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, chef-zero

Is there a way to get chef to reuse a powershell session or at least decrease the launch time of a new process? A run is spending 2 seconds performing not_if and only_if checks that use powershell (even if the PS code itself is instantaneous). It would be nice to improve this.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, what you see is what you get. If you're interested in working on it, a GitHub issue or pull request would be the right place to discuss.

Comment: I am. Any suggestions on a safe way to do this? Can you point me to the source for powershell_script?

Comment: The provider code is in https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/powershell_script.rb but you'll want to check out a bunch of other referenced stuffs, like a lot of the logic is in base classes and mixins. As for how to do this, I can't think of anything. You would probably have to run some kind of powershell daemon and reuse it across multiple execution. This sounds like a bad idea so you'll have to go pretty far to show it is safe.